# Working with large spreadsheets and files

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I've noticed when I run into not enough capacity or space on my computer running Excel 2010 when I then reboot my computer it allows me to do commands it previously did not allow.  Is this a RAM problem or some other feature/issue I am unaware of?

Comment: Can you specify what commands you were able to run after rebooting? Seems like a RAM issue, as you stated you had big spreadsheets. It could be anything however...

Comment: How large is the Excel file (Number of columns and rows or file size)? How much RAM does your system have? Is your OS 64-bit or 32-bit?

Comment: Have you checked your drive for free space?

Answer (score 0):

Because it recovers after a reboot, we know it is a problem with running out of RAM, not disk space, and we know that your computer seems to have less free RAM the longer it is left running. How often do you reboot? Windows should be rebooted often, at least every week. More likely though, I suspect some other program on your computer, besides Excel, is consuming the memory. Either some legitimate piece of software has a "memory leak" such that it consumes more and more memory over time, or your computer is infected with malware.

Comment: Windows should be rebooted often, at least every week.. I rarely see anyone leaving a computer on for more than 24 hours...

Comment: Yes, most Windows users don't, but there are exceptions. Also, a few people have discovered hibernation, which amounts to leaving your computer on indefinitely.